# circuitpython board library error (i got a raspberry pi pico)

Tags: python, adafruit, adafruit-circuitpython

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Coin\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\board.py", line 291, in <module>
    raise NotImplementedError(
NotImplementedError: Adafruit-PlatformDetect version 3.30.0 was unable to identify the board and/or microcontroller running the Windows platform. Please be sure you have the latest packages running: 'pip3 install --upgrade adafruit-blinka adafruit-platformdetect'
```

hey guys so i'm trying to learn circuitpython but i came across this error and i couldnt find the fix does anyone here know the fix?

Comment: What commands did you run that resulted in this error? From the error message it looks like you're trying to run a CircuitPython module on your host, under regular Python, rather than on the Pico using CircuitPython.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.